# How retrieve values from the Android Calculator

Tags: android, calculator

I am developing an application which the user taps on `EditText`, it displays the android calculator, so the user is able to do arithmetic operations.

I would like to retrieve the final value when the user presses the equal button in the android calculator and display it. Is that possible using the standard android calculator?

The code to open the calculator is the following:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();           
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(CALCULATOR_PACKAGE, CALCULATOR_CLASS));
startActivity(intent);
```

where,

```
String CALCULATOR_PACKAGE ="com.android.calculator2";
String CALCULATOR_CLASS ="com.android.calculator2.Calculator";
```

Any ideas or suggestion about how to retrieve the final value from the calculator?
Thanks

Comment: Hmmmm...not too sure on this one? I know there is the ContentProvider api that let's applications share data, but I'm not sure how you would go about this exactly. Waiting for answer from the more experience SO guys as well

Comment: "it displays the android calculator" -- there is no "the android calculator". Any device can have any calculator app it wants, or no calculator app. It certainly does not have to have `com.android.calculator2`.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible using the standard calculator, but that calculator is open source, so you could create your own calculator. The source contains a class called Logic (Logic.java); if you update the method evaluateAndShowResult() to automatically paste the result to the clipboard, and then do a paste in your app, you'd be ready.

As an alternative, if you really don't need the calculator's UI, you could just take Logic and trash the rest.

Comment: That sounds a good solution. Where can I get the code source of the calculator? Thanks

Answer (score -1):

You can start the Calculator with an startActivityForResult to get the Result back.

Here is an Example

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent();
myIntent.setClassName("com.android.calculator2", "com.android.calculator2.Calculator");
startActivityForResult(myIntent, CALC_INTENT_RETURN);
```

AND

```
   /**
     * Framework method called when return from a launched intent is available.
     */
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
        Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CALC_INTENT_RETURN) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    mCalculator.setFeatureValue(mCurrentInputField, Double.parseDouble(data.getAction()));
                    resetValue();
        }
    }
}
```

stripped down from
http://code.google.com/p/android-labs/source/browse/trunk/BistroMath/src/com/google/android/bistromath/BistroMath.java?r=6

Comment: This code does not work, at least with the current version of the calculator app, as the activity in question never calls `setResult()` (see https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_calculator/blob/master/src/com/android/calculator2/Calculator.java).

Comment: The class Calculator is not recognized, so I am not able to use it as possible solution of my issue. Thanks anyway